# Wrong std::condition_variable example on cppreference?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, race-condition

In their [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) usage of `std::condition_variable` they have essentially

```
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool ready = false;

void worker_thread()
{
    // Wait until main() sends data
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    cv.wait(lk, []{return ready;});
    // more ...
}

int main()
{
    std::thread worker(worker_thread);

    data = "Example data";
    // send data to the worker thread
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
        ready = true;
    }
    cv.notify_one();
    // more...
}
```

My problem now is the variable `ready` which is not declared `std::atomic*`.

**Why doesn't this introduce a race condition if spurious wakeup occurs?**

Comment: `ready` is synchronized by `m` in every case. A `conditional_variable` always reacquires the lock before evaluating it's condition.

Comment: Because `std::mutex` is involved

Comment: Couldn't spurious wakeup occur and a read and write of `ready` could  overlap?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ah. I understood after reading the docs again. Thank you. You are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no race condition.
Even if the condition variable spuriously wakes up, it must re-acquire the lock. hence, two things happen:

1. no thread can touch `ready` while the lock is held, as a lock protects it.
2. by re-acquiring the lock, the boolean must be synchronized, because the lock enforce memory order acquire, which causes `ready` to have the latest value.

So there is no way for race condition to happen.